# Nagios3 saying localhost is down on ping, but no ping check is written

Tags: nagios

Nagios3 and Ubuntu 14 with ping requests disabled.

The localhosts keeps reporting in the GUI nagios interface that it is down.

This is the default "localhost_nagios2.cfg" found in the conf.d dir after install:

```
# A simple configuration file for monitoring the local host
# This can serve as an example for configuring other servers;
# Custom services specific to this host are added here, but services
# defined in nagios2-common_services.cfg may also apply.
#

define host{
        use                     generic-host            ; Name of host template to use
        host_name               localhost
        alias                   localhost
        address                 127.0.0.1
        }

# Define a service to check the disk space of the root partition
# on the local machine.  Warning if < 20% free, critical if
# < 10% free space on partition.

define service{
        use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       localhost
        service_description             Disk Space
        check_command                   check_all_disks!20%!10%
        }



# Define a service to check the number of currently logged in
# users on the local machine.  Warning if > 20 users, critical
# if > 50 users.

define service{
        use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       localhost
        service_description             Current Users
        check_command                   check_users!20!50
        }


# Define a service to check the number of currently running procs
# on the local machine.  Warning if > 250 processes, critical if
# > 400 processes.

define service{
        use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       localhost
        service_description             Total Processes
                check_command                   check_procs!250!400
        }



# Define a service to check the load on the local machine.

define service{
    use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             Current Load
            check_command                   check_load!5.0!4.0!3.0!10.0!6.0!4.0
    }
```

This is pretty much out of the box config. I altered the generic-host so as not to ping anything:

```
# Generic host definition template - This is NOT a real host, just a template!

define host{
        name                            generic-host    ; The name of this host template
        notifications_enabled           1       ; Host notifications are enabled
        event_handler_enabled           1       ; Host event handler is enabled
        flap_detection_enabled          1       ; Flap detection is enabled
        failure_prediction_enabled      1       ; Failure prediction is enabled
        process_perf_data               1       ; Process performance data
        retain_status_information       1       ; Retain status information across program restarts
        retain_nonstatus_information    1       ; Retain non-status information across program restarts
                max_check_attempts              10
                notification_interval           0
                notification_period             24x7
                notification_options            d,u,r
                contact_groups                  admins
        register                        0       ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL HOST, JUST A TEMPLATE!
        }
```

The other servers i am monitoring are fine and nagios doesn't run any ping checks on them. however, nagios wont stop complaining that the local host is down with a critical state... on the PING:
[image]

I have scrutinized Google's offerings for over an hour now and cannot figure out how to turn this check off.

My Question:
Is this actually turned off and in a locked "down" state, or is there another setting i have missed to stop the local host running a ping check?

Thanks.
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use *something* for a host check, otherwise the state will never change.

Notice how it says "Last Check" was on the 17th, even though you took this screenshot on the 19th?

If you don't want to use `check_ping`, pick another plugin to use for a host check. Or just let it ping localhost; there's no harm in that, even though it seems unnecessary.

There's also `check_dummy`, which you can use to always return `UP` for the host check.